# multiple postbacks of a page on page_load when autopostback = true on a dropdown

Tags: c#-4.0

This is driving me crazy, tried searching solutions on google but nothing relevant came up. ok so this is the problem : I have user control having an update panel, its having a repeater which is having a dropdown in it. now `onSelectedInde`x change event of dropdown I want to perform some actions.
So when I set `autopostback= true` and bind an event handler my update panel keeps on updating the contents using async postbacks infinitely(in a loop). I cant really figure out the problem. If possible can anyone suggest an alternative to approach to do the same? I mean is there a way to do it without having `autopostback= true`?

**ascx code:**

```
<asp:updatepanel id="upd1" runat="server" childrenastrigger="true">
 <contenttemplate>
    <asp:repeater id="rpt" runat="server">
     <asp:dropdown="drp1" runat="server" autopostback="true" OnSelectedIndexchanged="ddl_selectindexchanged"/>
     </asp:repeater>
 </contenttemplate>
```

P.S : its a pseudocode and selectedindexchanged event doesnt gets fired even once but async postbacks occur in a loop on page load of this user control.